# Smart contract to refund ETH transfer

Tags: solidity, evm, out-of-gas

I wanna achieve smart contract to send ETH back to the sender on some conditions:

```
function() public payable {
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}
```

I am passing `gasLimit` equal to `4700000`:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: wallet, to: contract.address, value: ether(2), gasLimit: 4700000});
```

And still see error when running on `testrpc`:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

Sending ETH to other smart contract usually works fine. What's wrong with instant refund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the gasLimit not the gas. I think what you meant to send was:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: wallet, to: contract.address, value: ether(2), gas: 4700000});
```